# pick date from a line and compare with current date and print a different filed from the line which is picked up

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, timestamps

I have got the commands to pick up the date from a line comparing them with current date, I am looking to print another field from same line in `if-then` statement.

```bsh
cat /tmp/OutPrint |cut -d' ' -f 2 | while IFS= read line; do
    
    now=$(date | cut -d' ' -f 4)
    
    time_now=$(date -u -d "$now" +"%s")   #seconds
    time_line=$(date -u -d "$line" +"%s") #seconds
    
    difference=$(echo $((time_now - time_line)))
    
    if [ $difference -ge 2592000 ] 
    then
        echo "Time difference is greater than 30 days"
    else 
        echo "Time difference is less than 30 days"
    fi
done
```

Below is the content of my file from which I am comparing the date with the current date. If the difference is more than 30 days I need the first field to be printed in the `then` statement.

How can I print the first field in the `then` statement ?

Input:

```
anhtdg5 03-Jul-2019  
kjushr7 04-Aug-2020  
bhyusj3 09-Mar-2017  
losyej9 09-Mar-2017  
nhtgsy57 09-Mar-2017  
bpolise3 09-Mar-2017  
uioshye2 14-Mar-2018   
zsethfyu 23-Nov-2018  
cnhysge 23-Mar-2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the first field, but `cut` it off before sending it to `while`.

Why not simply use `read` to separate the fields:

```bsh
while read name date; do
    ...
    time_line=$(date -u -d "$date" +"%s")
    ...
    echo "$name"
done < /tmp/OutPrint
```

---

Your script has several additional complicated notations that somehow work, but could be written in better ways:

- Useless use of `cat`.
- Why you save an intermediate `$now` variable to use with `date` instead of use `date` directly:

  ```
  time_now=$(date -u +"%s")
  ```
- Useless use of `echo` to save an output of command to a variable:

  ```
  difference=$((time_now - time_line))
  ```
- You could also directly use it in your if statement instead of saving to a variable at all:

  ```
  if [ $((time_now - time_line)) -ge 2592000 ]
  ```